# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'df' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

stackoverflow community!

I use python3 to collect some information from a server, but I had this Error and I did not find a solution for it.

This is my code below :

```
from subprocess import check_output
disks = check_output(("df")).decode("utf-8").split('\n')
print(disks)
```

and this is the output:

```
df: /run/user/1001/doc: Operation not permitted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'df' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

`check_output()` it work with other commands for example: `check_output(("uname")).decode("utf-8")` the output is: `Linux`

Why it work with other commands, but it don't work with `df` command? and what is the solution for this problem?

the command `df` it work when I run it from the terminal

Comment: Can you give more details for this code of yours?

Comment: Does this command run correctly when you do it yourself in the shell?

Comment: @Numerlor  the command it work when I run it in the terminal.

Comment: Could you post the output of `df; echo $?`?

Comment: @Sören the output is: ```df: /run/user/1001/doc: Operation not permitted
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay        273095012 171849760  87303136  67% /
tmpfs              65536         0     65536   0% /dev
shm                65536         0     65536   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda5      273095012 171849760  87303136  67% /
tmpfs            1969516         0   1969516   0% /proc/asound
tmpfs            1969516         0   1969516   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs            1969516         0   1969516   0% /sys/firmware
1```

Comment: `df: /run/user/1001/doc: Operation not permitted`
sounds like a good reason to return a non-zero status.

Comment: Not a programming question, but a unix tool question.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python code is fine as such. If you want to avoid the traceback, `subprocess.run` lets you do that.

```
from subprocess import run
disks = run(["df"], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(disks.stdout)
```

The `check` in `check_output` means specifically that Python will raise an error if the subprocess fails.
But Python is not doing anything useful here. Simply

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["df"])
```

would do the same thing with less hassle. (Running `df` without Python would obviously be more straightforward still.)

Comment: I guess there is no reason _per se_ to use a list instead of a tuple around `"df"`, but the convention to use a list is certainly strong, so I changed that too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a permissions error. You could probably get a better error indication by doing that directly in Python. The following function does the equivalent.

```
import os


def df(path="/"):
    """Return file system blocks used and free.

    Values are same as output of df command.
    """
    stat = os.statvfs(path)
    return (((stat.f_blocks - stat.f_bfree) * 8),
            (stat.f_bavail * (stat.f_frsize // 512)))
```